# Firebase for iOS - console stuck in Not configured for Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, console, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I already configured tons of apps for APNS in Firebase and it was always painless. Today I'm tring to configure another one which I already implemented the entire SDK for Messaging, added the GoogleService-Info.plist, enabled the bundle ID for Push Notifications, runned the app with Firebase smoothly in a device.

But the Firebase console configuration screen for Notifications doesn't let me upload my certificates or my APNs Auth Key (which I already have too).

The upload buttons are missing, the "fields" are not doing anything, I already tried switching browsers and even switching the computer (Windows based).

I'm working with a mac, tried Google Chrome, tried Safari, tried Chrome for Windows (in another computer) and nothing changes... I'm stuck in this screen.[image]

**EDIT: I inspected the console webpage and saw that my browser is getting 404 from Firebase server connection getApnsAuthKey:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "APNS cert not found for requested project and bundle ID",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: that's strange. I checked I on my account I can see the buttons (on the right, inside the grey boxes like "No APNs auth key").
Maybe check if you have any chrome update,  extension you can disable, or try from the incognito window.

Comment: Has anyone been able to solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with Firebase Console. It looks like temporary issue on server side. So here is my solution (it works for me):

1. Open the [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/**your-project**/settings/cloudmessaging/](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/)
2. Press cmd+option+i in Chrome to open Dev Tools
3. Using Dev Tools inspect grey boxes and find `<button/>` "Upload" element
4. Remove `display: none !important;` rule from this `<button/>`
5. Also disable `visibility: hidden;` property of button's parent div element

After that you can upload certificates or APNS key as it should be in normal.

Comment: Although it's not an official solution, it helped me uploading the Auth Key.. Thanks @cmdeviant :)
Idk about the others but this is a HUGE firebase console problem. Firebase should be looking at this URGENTLY.

Comment: Work perfect can't believe the security of not being an owner is that easy to bypass

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase may be updated with new UI -> new elements at this time (*November 2017*).

- Inspect the `Upload` button
- Remove `disabled="disabled"` attributed in the `button` tag
  [image]
- `Upload` button is enabled!
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason the Upload button was disabled was not shown in the UI, but was visible when inspecting the elements.

> You must be an owner to upload an APNs auth key

My permissions are that of `Editor`, seems you need to be `Owner` to upload.

Comment: This case is different, already had that, but never equal to what I had at the time of the question. It seems they fixed it.